# .NET 6 MVC enabling razor runtime compilation breaks program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I followed the simple steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio to enable runtime compilation of my cshtml views.

However as soon as i add ".AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()" to the builder:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

This will result in an error when running the project:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
  Source=System.Linq
  StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType[TResult](IEnumerable source)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionDescriptorProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 pageRouteModelProviders, IOptions`1 mvcOptionsAccessor, IOptions`1 pagesOptionsAccessor)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllerRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String name, String pattern, Object defaults, Object constraints, Object dataTokens)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\---\---\---\Cshtml test\Cshtml test\Program.cs:line 25
```

EDIT:

Here is the code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: What packages do you have installed in your project?

Comment: It's just a completely new unmodified project of the type "ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) where i add the Nuget package as described in the microsoft documentation.

Comment: I just created a new .NET 6 project with the "ASP.NET Core Web App" template. Installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` version `6.0.3` and could start the project fine. Could you try re-creating the project?

Comment: MaartenDev, even when you added the .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() to the builder?

Comment: I tried creating a new project on my work PC also, with the exact same error as a result. Default ASP.NET MVC project with no other changes. As soon as i add the .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation the project does not run properly anymore.

Comment: Update dotnet SDK to 6.0.201 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40609

Comment: Balazska, thanks! Updating Visual Studio 2022 to latest version fixed the issue.

Comment: Temporary solution for this issue is to add this line to the builder:
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

Answer (score -2):

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
```

Adding `addmvc` fixed it

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more on why `builder.Services.AddMvc();` worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).