# Runtime Compilation of Razor Pages Does Not Work .NET 8 VS2022

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am having a hard time enabling runtime compilation of Razor pages under IIS v10.0, using Visual Studio 2022 17.8.8, .NET 8.0.103 (Windows 11).

I have followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio and added the required nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` (v8.03). Configured the services as instructed, except I am not limiting the runtime compilation to only the dev environment. I want it active in the published site (yes I know what I am doing, I am aware of the potential performance problems, etc.)

Once the site is published to a directory on local IIS, it works *per se*, but the **runtime compilation doesn't**. There are no `.cshtml` pages copied upon publishing and so nothing to modify in place.

OK, so I tried changing their "Copy to Output Directory" setting in the Solution Explorer to "Copy always". They then get copied upon publishing, but are inert - changing their content has no effect on the application in the browser. Apparently the pages still get compiled into a static assembly upon publishing.

I looked at some previous answers, for example this: [Razor Page Runtime Compilation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952025/razor-page-runtime-compilation-not-working) (accepted solution concerning `RazorCompileOnPublish` setting does not work) and this
[.NET 6 MVC enabling razor runtime compilation breaks program.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717192/net-6-mvc-enabling-razor-runtime-compilation-breaks-program-cs) (different, unrelated problem) and their suggestions didn't help me.

I have also enlisted Claude (AI) and it had some suggestions, none of which worked. I need some human intelligence to help me out here, please.

I should mention that I think I remember doing it before, with previous versions of .NET Core and VS, and I don't recall it being such a pain. This should be simple: Razor Pages are presumably meant to be dynamic and easy to setup, as opposed to MVC.

`<rant>`I need a runtime-compiled, essentially a scripting, solution to creating dynamic websites. This is becoming progressively more difficult with each toolchain update. Classic ASP anyone? If it weren't horrible VBScript I would still use it, but at this point, I was hoping for something up-to-date and modern, though.`</rant>`

Comment: _"Razor Pages are meant to be dynamic and easy to setup."_ - Says who?

Comment: Does the `RazorCompileOnPublish` suggestion at least result in the .cshtml files being published?

Comment: @KirkLarkin No, they still don't get published, unless "Copy always" is set.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my reply? Please feel free to share any detailed information to us and it will be very helpful for us to better work out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow my steps.

1.Refer to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation (v8.03)` as you have done, and copy the cshtml file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="8.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PageFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\Pages\**\*.cshtml" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Copy .cshtml files from Pages folder after publishing -->
    <Target Name="CopyPageFilesAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(PageFiles)"
          DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Pages\%(RecursiveDir)"
    />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

2.Add the service

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

3.Test

files copied

[image]

dynamic pages

[image]
[image]

Comment: @FengziZhou Sorry, but no, it still doesn't work. The only new elements that you introduced relative to what I had were `PageFiles` and `Target` nodes in the `.cshtml`. However, thy make no diffrence: the files are still not copied. The only way I can get them to copy on publish is by setting the "Copy to Output Directory" value and then they are still not used.

Comment: @Optimax Let us check the key steps. **1.** Please kindly check the file path should be Pages under `bin\Release\net8.0\publish`, as in my test there is also a Pages under .net8.0 and it behaves as you described. **2.** Start the `projectname .application` file under publish and open the url in console, modify the cshtml file under publish/pages to test the dynamic page. **3.** If all the steps failed, could you please share your project settings, or start a new project to test since in my test I am using all default settings and it works.